# How to make a div change direction to RTL?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this div change direction to RTL right to left using
css.

HTML:

```html
    <div class="btn">

    <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. You need to set the direction css property of that div to rtl but you also need to set unicode bidi to embed or override:

   .rtldiv{
   direction: rtl;
   unicode-bidi: embed;
   }

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

2. Set the dir html property for that div:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir

Answer (score 0):

its done from CSS like this :

```
.buttonid {
direction: rtl;
}
```